# How to display an image from s3 bucket in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm trying to create a user profile page. I`ve got it so a user can upload an image and I am currently struggling with how to display that image now.

The only way I could find were the following:

```
<img src="{{Storage::disk('s3')->url($image_path)}}" style="height:400px !important;" alt="logo">
<img src="{{$image_path}}" style="height:400px !important;" alt="logo">
```

However, neither of these seems to work and I`m not sure what else to try. My code from my controller to get the image path:

```
$image_path = Storage::disk('s3')->url(
            "images"."/".$auth_id
        );
```

My code from my controller to store the images :

```
public function uploadPost(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    $id = Auth::id();
 
    Storage::disk('s3')->putFileAs('images', $request->image,$id);


    return view("/pages/teachers-page/teacher_profile")
        ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.');
}
```

Comment: I figured it out. I've not got the right permissions as when I try the link on its own I get "Access Denied".  I've set the bucket to public and tried the following code to set the path to `public Storage::disk('s3')->setVisibility($path,'public');` but its still not working. Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out the code above works as intended. I just needed to change the permissions of my IAM User in AWS.